# List Search Box

Tags: 2013, list, search, list-view

Which is the best way to search for items inside a list? (by UI.)

I am using the default **search box** of the view, but it does not have the **contains** (like).

To find the results I have to use wildcard symbol `*`

Comment: Try using CSWP.

Comment: I tried, using CSWB with a Search Box, but still same problem